# Eclipse Clear Debug Shell

Tags: eclipse, debugging

This is kind of a weird question so bear with me.

I found a way to allow unlimited output in the 'debug shell' view and then I executed a function in the Eclipse "debug shell" (used to be known as 'display') and it produced an output so large that it breaks my Eclipse. This forced me to reboot eclipse. Unfortunately, now everytime I open Eclipse it tries to open that view again, and so my eclipse is sort of permanently broken. Is there a settings file I can go into somewhere and dump so that it doesn't keep trying to load that garbage everytime I boot Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: Try launching eclipse with `-clean` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies somewhere in the eclipse .metadata directory (at the root of your workspace). I closed my eclipse, deleted this directory, and then restarted my Eclipse and was able to open up the debug shell again. Keep in mind this will delete all your Eclipse settings and have to restart from scratch again, however its worth it for me because I have to have this debug shell.